# Pass a parameter that contains dots in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I need to pass an attribute (contains dots) as a parameter to my PowerShell script. I want to replace an existing attribute value in JSON file using this script.

Tried using customobject, loop, split using dot.

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$logFolder = "C:\Test",
    [string]$jsonAttribute = "Data.DefaultConnection.ConnectionString",
    [string]$jsonvalue = "new value"
)

$AppConfig = "$logFolder\*\appsettings.PRODUCTION.json" -f $PSScriptRoot, $global:LatestBuild
$appsettings = Get-Content $AppConfig -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$appsettings | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $AppConfig -Force
$pathToJson = "$logFolder\*\appsettings.PRODUCTION.json"
$data.Data.DefaultConnection.ConnectionString = $jsonvalue
$data | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $pathToJson
```

Comment: Can you format this so it becomes readable?

Comment: What about your code doesn't work the way you expected, i.e. what did you expect the code to do, and what does it actually do? Please provide samples of input and actual output as well as the corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameter as a string. Here you can see an example of how it doesn't work if the param is passed unwrapped. Then, the next time I wrap the param in quotes and it works:
[image]